# Unable to Load Library mongo_embedded

Tags: android, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I am trying to use MongoDB in an Android project by following this guide:
https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/find-documents-in-mongodb/

But the application is crashing at the following line:
`val mongoClient = stitchClient.getServiceClient(RemoteMongoClient.factory, "mongodb-atlas")`
with the following message

```
com.mongodb.embedded.client.MongoClientEmbeddedException: The mongo embedded library could not be initialized
    Server error message: Unable to load the Mongo Embedded Library.
    Please either: Set the libraryPath when calling MongoEmbeddedCAPI.create or 
    Ensure the library is set on the jna.library.path or the java.library.path system property.
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'mongo_embedded': Native library (android-x86/libmongo_embedded.so) not found in resource path (.)
```

But when I run the application on my phone it is working.
Any ideas why it is crashing on the virtual emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the client is crashing is because the mongoDB stitch SDK needs to run on a 64 bit device (see [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/mobile/getting-started/)). Almost all android devices built now are 64 bit however the emulator in android studio is 32 bit by default.

To fix this go to the AVD Manager and create a new Virtual Device that supports x86_64 (this is 64 bit) instead of x86 (this is 32 bit).